# How to convert image storage order from channel-height-width to height-width-channel?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector, computer-vision

I would like to know how to convert an image stored as a 1D `std::vector<float>` from CHW format (Channel, Height, Width) to HWC format (Height, Width, Channel) in C++. The format change is needed due to requirements of a neural network.

I used OpenCV to read and show the image as below:

```
cv::namedWindow("Screenshot", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cv::imshow("Screenshot", rgbImage);
```

Then I converted the `cv::Mat` `rgbImage` to a 1D `std::vector<float>` in format CHW:

```
size_t channels = 3;
std::vector<float> data(channels*ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT*ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH);
for(size_t j=0; j<ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT; j++){
    for(size_t k=0; k<ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH; k++){
        cv::Vec3b intensity = rgbImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, k);
        for(size_t i=0; i<channels; i++){
            data[i*ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT*ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH + j*ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT + k] = (float) intensity[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert the format of `std::vector<float>` data to HWC. How can I do this?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` of`deep-learning` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: CHW, HWC wut please? Be clear please, instead of speaking in unintelligible acronym and buzzword riddles.

Comment: Nothing like a few TLAs to spread confusion.

Comment: Do you know how to read and write binary files? If not, you should learn how to do so. This site is for specific programming questions, not for code writing requests.

Comment: I edited my question and provided more details to my question

Answer (score 3):

I found some description of the "CHW" and "HWC" formats [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/276).

If the storage order is HWC, it means that

> Each sample is stored as a column-major matrix `(height, width)` of `float[numChannels]` `(r00, g00, b00, r10, g10, b10, r01, g01, b01, r11, g11, b11)`.

Thus a pixel `(x, y, c)` is found using

```
xStride = channels;
yStride = channels * width;
cStride = 1;

data[x*xStride + y*yStride + c*cStride]
```

If the storage order is CHW, it means that each channel is a different plane. A pixel `(x, y, c)` is found using

```
xStride = 1;
yStride = width;
cStride = width * height;

data[x*xStride + y*yStride + c*cStride]
```

Note that in the code in the question, `data[i*ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT*ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH + j*ROS_IMAGE_HEIGHT + k]` is incorrect, `j` is the y-coordinate and should be multiplied by `ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH`.

The code in the question can be modified to yield a `std::vector` in the HWC format by replacing the line in the innermost loop by:

```
data[i + j*ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH*channels + k*channels] = (float) intensity[i];
```

Comment: `data[i + j*ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH*channels + k*channels]` => `data[i + (j * ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH + k) * channels]`

Comment: @Scheff: Yes, that is how I would normally write it, but I wanted the code to be clear and match the stuff I wrote above. I guess a good compiler will optimize both forms to the same machine code anyway.

Comment: Yeah. I thought twice whether this would be an improvement at all. (It surely wouldn't if `ROS_IMAGE_WIDTH` and `channels` were constants.) Just ignore it. ;-) (Beside of this, you got my upvote.) ;-)